# NSString to NSDate conversion issue

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I have `Date is 2012-09-25 09:33:10 +0000` , using

```
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
  NSDate *d = [dateFormatter dateFromString:sDate];
```

// sDate = @"2012-September-21"

But i get nil , instead of a formatter date. What can be the issue ?

Comment: Is the value of `sDate` equal to `2012-September-21` or `2012-09-25 09:33:10 +0000`?

Comment: I think this will help you http://kamleshwar.com/blog/2011/09/convert-nsstring-to-nsdate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your sDate = @"2012-September-21", it does not have time (hour minutes and seconds) in your string **sDate**. So you should set your format like this

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't include time into string. You also need to fix the locale:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2012-September-21"];
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not clear that what is input, but i have tested with below given input it is working

```
NSString *dateString = @"2012-09-25 09:33:10";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]   autorelease];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```